Center form in the middle of the screen
Sorry for this noob question, I'm not as good with css and html.
But i just want a simple and nice loginpage for my website.
I try to make a login form in the middle of the screen, but it drifts when i resize the screen.
Can anyone please point me in the right direction with this one.
css
body{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    height:100vh;
  }

.body_bg{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.col-light{
    background-color: #0055ff;
    height: 100vh;
}

.login{
    
    position: fixed;
    top: 35%;
    right: 27%;
    width: 50em;
}

input.login{
    margin-top: 50px;
}


html

    <body class="body_bg">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="row login ">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-light">
                    <div class="center">
                        <div class="login ">
                            <div class="row mt-4">
                                <div class="col-md-3 text-end ">
                                    <h1 class="display-6"><?= $lang['username'] ?></h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 align-middle">
                                    <input type="text" class="align-middle form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt-4">
                                <div class="col-md-3 text-end">
                                    <h1 class="display-6"><?= $lang['password'] ?></h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <button class="btn btn-success"><?= $lang['login'] ?></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



